# How to use array for Media player using CustomListAdapter for different tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabactivity

I have three Tabbed Activities each with their own images and sounds arrays. The images and sounds are passed to the CustomListAdapter and returned as a List:

TabActivity:

```
public  class Tab1Activity extends Fragment {

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

        String[] sound = {"path/to/media/file.mp3wl.gif",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3",
                "",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3",
                "path/to/media/file.mp3"
        };


         String[] images = {"ImagePathwl.gif",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg",
                "",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg",
                "ImagePath/image.jpg"
        };

        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), sound, images);

        list=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

              list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    final int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                mp.setDataSource(sound[+position]);
                                mp.prepare();
                                mp.start();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("GGGGGG", "prepare() failed");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.reset();
            }
        });


        return rootView;

}
```

CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final String[] sound;
private final String[] images;

 public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] sound, images) {
        super(context, R.layout.animal_list, itemname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;
        this.sound=sound;
        this.image=image;
    }

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {

 LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.animal_list, null,false);

                imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

                if (!imgid[position].isEmpty()) {
            Picasso.with(context) // Context
                    .load(imgid[position]) // URL or file
                    .into(imageView); // An ImageView object to show the loaded image
        }

}
}
```

How to play the sounds with the imageView in customAdapter for different Tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the media player function to the adapter and into an onclick there and passed the array sounds to the adapter.